# float elements to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Code**

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPreCurrentdate" data-provide="datepicker" placeholder="Enter a Start Date">
  <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPostCurrentdate" data-provide="datepicker" placeholder="Enter an End Date">


  <!-- want the below section to move to the right. -->
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-server"></i>
  </div>
  <input type="number" id="txtResltsPerPage" class="form-control" ng-model="pageSize" placeholder="Results per Page 10">
</div>
```

[image]
With the above code all the elements appear next to each other as shown in the above picture. I need the last `<input>` and `<div>` elements in the above code to appear on the right side of the `form`.

Answer (score 1):

wrap this:

```
<div class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-server"></i>
</div>
<input type="number" id="txtResltsPerPage" class="form-control" ng-model="pageSize" placeholder="Results per Page 10">
```

with  a `<div class="pull-right"></div>`, see [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats) about helpers classes floats

Comment: tried this but didn't do as expected.  when I Wrap that section inside a <div> all the elements are scattared as shown in the second picture in the  question.

Comment: can you create a fiddle please?